# Forwarding DHCPOFFER through bridged OpenVPN

Tags: dhcp, openvpn

Setup:

host <---> OpenVPN-client with DHCP-helper <---> OpenVPN-server <---> DHCP-Server

Except "host" everything is setup with static IP's and routing works fine.
All stations can ping each other.

The DHCPDISCOVER is send to the server via DHCP-helper but the (unicast) DHCPOFFER 
from the server does not even reach the OpenVPN-client.

Using tcpdump -i tap0 on both sides shows REQUEST and REPLY on server-side but
only REQUEST on the client.

Why is the REPLY not forwarded and how can this be accoomplished?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm currently facing the exact same problem using server-bridge directive in the openvpn server configuration.
My Client is issuing tons of DHCP Discovers who are broadcasted to the network.
I've used wireshark on other machines and they are able to see these packets. Structure below: host with openVPN client < -- > OpenVPN Server (10.11.2.26) < -- > DHCP Server (10.11.2.1) Edit: If you're using an vmWare Hypervisor, there are some issues with promiscious packets blocking by the vswitch.
check blog post: http://www.jeremycole.com/blog/2010/03/11/openvpn-bridge-under-vmware-esxi/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since DHCP-packets are not routed, the problem was that only client-side of the VPN-tunnel was bridged to eth.

Solution: both ends of the VPN-tunnel had to be bridged to the physical device.

Keyword:  site-to-site bridging